# Amazon Advertising API ItemSearch: Get more than 10 pages / 100 results?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm trying to use the Python wrapper for the Amazon Advertising API (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/), but when I try to do an ItemSearch and try to access the 11th page, I get something along the lines of:

```
The value you specified for ItemPage is invalid. ... between 1 and 10
```

I know in order to avoid this problem, I could just perform another search query, but is there a way to start the search query on a certain page? Or is there a way (for books) to set a boundary for the publishing year? I just need a way so that I could make my search results smaller, so that I don't run into this error. Right now this is how I'm calling it:

```
results = api.item_search('Books', ResponseGroup='Images,Large', 
                              AssociateTag='qwerty', Publisher=kwd)
```

Where kwd is just a publisher name obtained from a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon will only give you the first 10 pages (as of API version 2011-08-01). You could run slightly different searches to get more results, but these would also be restricted to the first 10 pages.

Comment: So basically the only way around this restriction is to make the queries more focused? (ex: using different values for min and max price)

Comment: So I ended up using different values for MinPrice and MaxPrice. Even though apparently there's a bug in the API that doesn't really filter the results correctly, it still allows me to get a lot more results than before.

Comment: @raymond If you discover a bug in the API (and even have a workaround), send it to me or the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/python-amazon-product-api-devel). Input is always appreciated!

Comment: Hey basti, I posted the bug in the mailing list. Hopefully Amazon gets their act together and fixes it!

Comment: Can I access the 11th page using paid API? Please help me.

Comment: I'm not aware of a paid option, so I'm afraid there is nothing you can do. Sorry.

Comment: @basti How amazon website shows more than 10 pages then?  Are they not using item search API?

Comment: @TBAG I don't think they have this limitation. You used to be able to access all pages once upon a time...

Comment: @basti Now they have that restriction. :(

Answer (score -1):

The Amazon Product Advertising API returns up to ten items per search request.
Anyway, the ItemPage parameter can be used to fetch the specific set/page of items to be returned from the available Search Results. The number of items returned in a page is determined by the ItemCount parameter. For e.g. if the third set of 5 items (i.e. items numbered 11 to 15) are desired for a search request, you may specify ItemPage as 3 and ItemCount as 5.
For further info: https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/search-items.html